# Drawing 2 lines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation

If i have 2 lines on a page

how would i animate the first line to reach the second line's position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a 'counter' variable that will be the percentage of the distance the line has travelled between the two locations. Initialize it to zero because it starts at the beginning position. Add a timer and each time it ticks you increment the 'counter' and invalidate the client area so that a repaint occurs. Once the 'counter' hits 100 and so it 100% of the way to the target you disable the timer as no longer being needed.

In the paint routine you already know the start position and the end position so just draw the line at the 'counter' percentage between the two. So given you know startX and you know endX your painted version is startX + ((endX - startX) / 100 * counter). Do this for each of the top, left, right and bottom of the line and you are done.

Comment: I edited my question. I thought i could just compare w2 with w and h2 with h until they are both equal and then stop... but... this doesn't quite work. Would you be able to expand on your idea?

Comment: Replace (w * (int)frame) with (w + ((w2 - w) * frame))

Comment: Your MoveLine is incrementing frame by 0.02 but is looping 126 times! So it will move 2.52 times the actual distance. Make it loop 50 times as that will result in an end frame of 1.

Comment: ahhh false alarm. When i do that, both lines vanish into the abyss :S not sure why that's happening?

Comment: hmm fixed that bug.. but it still continues to move off the page... also, the transition to the destination line is extremely blocky...

Comment: To make it smoother you need to change the number of iterations in the MoveLine and change the frame += to be (1 / number of iterations).

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistake you have blink, and this is your problem?
Try use this [BufferedGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics.aspx)
small example

```
System.Drawing.Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext dc = new BufferedGraphicsContext();
    BufferedGraphics backbuffer = dc.Allocate(g, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), g.VisibleClipBounds.Size.ToSize()));
    backbuffer.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, 10, 10, 10, 100);
    backbuffer.Render(g);
```

Comment: If i mistake, i'll delete this answer